# Highy non-linear PDE involving directional derivative

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, differential-operators, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let the convolution of two function $f$ and $g$ be defined over $\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)$ as followed

\begin{equation}\label{ConvoDef}
\left(f*g\right)\circ(\textbf{x},t) = \int_{0}^{t}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}^{}{f(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y},t-s)g(\textbf{y},s)d\textbf{y}ds}}
\end{equation}

Let $$f(\textbf{x},t):\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
$$\Phi(\textbf{x},t):\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, $$ and $$\phi(\textbf{x},t):\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$  be a known smooth continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^3$ for each point in time $t\in[0,\infty)$ and let $$\textbf{g}(\textbf{x},t):\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)$$ be known smooth vector field (meaning the components are smooth). Does their exist a smooth vector field $$\textbf{v}:\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)$$ such that

\begin{equation}
\label{Eq13}
\begin{split}
f(\textbf{x},t) + \textbf{v}_i(\textbf{x},t) +&D_{\phi\star \textbf{v}_i}\biggl( \phi(\textbf{x},t)+ \phi(\textbf{x},t)\star\textbf{v}_i(\textbf{x},t)\biggr)  \\
\\
+ & D_{\left[\Phi,\Phi,\Phi\right]}\left(\biggl(\phi(\textbf{x},t)\star\textbf{v}_i(\textbf{x},t)\right)\biggr)=\textbf{g}_i(\textbf{x},t)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
with intial condition $$\textbf{v}\left(\textbf{x},0\right) = \textbf{v}_0\left(\textbf{x}\right)$$
for each $i\in \{1,2,3\}$?